# ¿Qué hace el método Count() en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo entendido que cuando recorro un vector, lo hago con `length`, pero veo que también usan el `Count()`.

¿Para qué sirve y que diferencia hay?

Por ejemplo:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < vector.Count(); i++) {

 }
```

Comment: ¿Por vector te refieres a un `Array`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cuando se usan colecciones como listas o vectores el metodo para obtener el tamaño de la colección es Count(). Por otro lado cuando manejamos arreglos o cadenas de texto el metodo que se utiliza es Length(), simplemente depende de si es una colección o arreglo pero ambos devuelven el tamaño.

Comment: Para Arrays se recomiendo `.Length`, para List, `Count`, `String` no tiene ningún método `Length()`. Esta respuesta está totalmente erronea.

Answer (score 3):

Si por vector te refieres a un `Array`

```
.Length
```

`.Length` es una propiedad de `Array<T>` que se refiere a la longitud del array es decir para cuantos objetos del tipo `T` se ha separado la memoria.

```
.Count()
```

`.Count()` es un método de extensión de LINQ de `IEnumerable<T>` (Array implementa `IEnumerable<T>`)

Es un método que obtiene la cantidad de elementos dependiendo del tipo subyacente de diversas maneras, por lo general, obteniendo un enumerador e iterando hasta llegar al final del `IEnumerable<T>` (Hay excepciones)

Esta forma es equivalente a llamar

```
Enumerable.Count(a)
```

Para saber cuál de los dos se debe usar en que caso veamos lo que genera el compilador.

Por ejemplo para el siguiente código:

```
var array = new []{ 1, 2, 3 };

var count1 = array.Count();
var count2 = Enumerable.Count(array);
```

El compilador genera el siguiente código `CIL` en LINQPad:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, ambas `count1` y `count2` son inicializadas con el resultado de llamar al método `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<Int32>`. Esto demuestra que las expresiones son equivalentes.

Sin embargo si utilizamos `.Length`

```
var array = new []{ 1, 2, 3 };
var length = array.Length;
```

Genera el siguiente código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual ni siquiera vemos la llamada a `.Length` sino que ya existe en `CIL` una operación `ldlen` para acceder obtener el número de elementos de un array, lo cual es una optimización.

#### En el caso  de `List<T>`

List no tiene una propiedad `Length` pero si tiene una propiedad `Count` además del método de extensión `Count()`.

Para el siguiente código

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3};
var count1 = list.Count;
var count2 = list.Count();
```

Se genera lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá ocurre algo interesante, como podemos ver en la primera llamada a `Count` se accede al `getter` de la propiedad `Count` (`get_Count`) mientras que la llamada al método de extensión `Count()` funciona igual que en el caso de `Array<T>` lo cual hace una llamada al método `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count<Int32>`

En general como se puede observar cuando tengas disponible la propiedad `Length` o `Count` en el caso de `List<T>` úsalo ya que será la forma más rápida de acceder a los elementos. Si no existe esa propiedad entonces usa `Count()` que funciona para cualquier `IEnumerable<T>`

Answer (score 2):

> **Nota: Esta es una traducción a la respuesta de [gbjbaanb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13744/gbjbaanb) en la pregunta [count vs length vs size in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection/300540#300540)**

`Length()` tiende a referirse a elementos contiguos - una cadena(`String`) tiene una longitud, por ejemplo.

`Count()` tiende a referirse al número de elementos de una colección.

`Size()` tiende a referirse al tamaño de la colección, a menudo esto puede ser diferente de la longitud(`length`) en casos como vectores (o cadenas), puede haber 10 caracteres en una cadena, pero el almacenamiento está reservado para 20. También puede referirse a un número de elementos.

`Capacity()` se utiliza para referirse específicamente al espacio asignado en la colección y no al número de elementos válidos en ella. Si un tipo de dato tiene **capacity x** y **size y** definidos, entonces **size** normalmente se refiere al número de elementos reales.

Creo que el punto principal es el lenguaje humano y los modismos, el tamaño de una cadena no parece muy obvio, mientras que la longitud de un conjunto es igualmente confuso, aunque se podría utilizar para referirse a la misma cosa (número de elementos ) en una colección de datos.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo referir material a otros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). [count vs length vs size in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/300540/457643)

Comment: _Tengo unas dudas de tu respuesta:_ ¿`Length()` es un método?, lo digo por los paréntesis. / Cuando indicas `Count()`, ¿Te refieres a la propiedad o al método extendido? / ¿Que relación tiene `Size()` y `Capacity()` con un `Array`?

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que al decir `vector` te estás refiriendo a una `List<T>` o a un `Array`.

La respuesta es que no existe diferencia alguna, ya que ambos obtienen el número de elementos en una secuencia. En el caso de un `Array`, puedes usar el método `Count()` debido a que es un método de extensión de Linq y de igual manera es un objeto iterable.

En estas páginas puedes encontrar la documentación oficial para la propiedad [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length.aspx) y el método [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.count.aspx) (en inglés).